# Promises. Не работает последовательность

Tags: javascript, jquery, очередь

Здравствуйте. Пишу код с использованием Обещаний для последовательного запуска функций. Только пару дней как разбираюсь с ними для улучшения кода (ибо раньше была ёлочка из коллбэков);
Так вот. Есть функция анимации вывода текста на экран Animal():

```
function Animal(string) {
    var a = ''; //variable which will be entered character by character string
    var i= 0;//Letter counter
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    $('body').scrollTop($('body').append(p).height());
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
        Anima();
        function Anima() {//Function of Animation   
            a+=string[i];
            i++;
            $('p').last().text(a);
           var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
            if(i==string.length){
                clearTimeout(timer);
                resolve();
            };
        };
    });
};
```

И функция AnimalPause() для изображения пауз(выводится на экран строка из точек и сразу же удаляется):

```
function AnimalPause(string) {
var a = ''; //variable which will be entered character by character string
var i= 0;//Letter counter
var p = document.createElement('p');
$('body').scrollTop($('body').append(p).height());
return promise = new Promise(function (resolve) {
    Anima();
    function Anima() {//Function of Animation   
        a+=string[i];
        i++;
        $('p').last().text(a);
        var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
        if(i==string.length){
            clearTimeout(timer);
            $('p').last().remove();
            resolve();
        };
    };
});
};
```

Все сделал, вроде бы. И, если выводить последовательно строки через .then() - всё работает. И, если выводить последовательно строки с использованием цикла - тоже всё работает:

```
Animal('..........')
        .then(() => Animal('---Hello! CONSOLE v 1.0.1 is working!---'))
        .then(() => Animal('To see all commands u can use type -help'))
        .then(() => Animal('DONE'))
```

или так:

```
var chain = Promise.resolve();
pause.forEach(function(txt){
                    chain = chain.then(() => AnimalPause(txt))});

var pause = [
    '...',
    '.....',
    '....',
    '.........'
];
```

Но если через .then() Последовательно выводить текст, потом задержку, потом - текст, рушится:
(Задержка выводится после того, как выведется текст):

```
function Hello() {
var chain = Animal('..........')
        .then(() => Animal('---Hello! CONSOLE v 1.0.1 is working!---'))
        .then(() => Animal('To see all commands u can use type -help'))
        .then(function() {
                 return Pause(chain);
//               pause.forEach(function(txt){
//                   chain = chain.then(() => AnimalPause(txt))})
            })
        .then(() => Animal('DONE'))

};
Hello();

function Pause (chain) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
        pause.forEach(function(txt){
                    chain = chain.then(() => AnimalPause(txt))});
        resolve();
    })
}
```

Почему? Ну..и как исправить? :)

По совету @Grundy в комментарии скидываю код для тестирования

```js
var pause = [
  '...',
  '.....',
  '....',
  '.........'
];

function Animal(string) {
  var a = ''; //variable which will be entered character by character string
  var i = 0; //Letter counter
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  $('body').scrollTop($('body').append(p).height());
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    Anima();

    function Anima() { //Function of Animation   
      a += string[i];
      i++;
      $('p').last().text(a);
      var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
      if (i == string.length) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        resolve();
      };
    };
  });
};

function AnimalPause(string) {
  var a = ''; //variable which will be entered character by character string
  var i = 0; //Letter counter
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  $('body').scrollTop($('body').append(p).height());
  return promise = new Promise(function(resolve) {
    Anima();

    function Anima() { //Function of Animation   
      a += string[i];
      i++;
      $('p').last().text(a);
      var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
      if (i == string.length) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('p').last().remove();
        resolve();
      };
    };
  });
};


function Pause(chain) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    pause.forEach(function(txt) {
      chain = chain.then(() => AnimalPause(txt))
    });
    resolve();
  })
};

function Hello() {
  var chain = Animal('..........')
    .then(() => Animal('---Hello! CONSOLE v 1.0.1 is working!---'))
    .then(() => Animal('To see all commands u can use type -help'))
    .then(function() {
      return Pause(chain); //Вы заметите, что строка пауз выводится после вывода на экран строки "DONE". Должно быть наоборот
    })
    .then(() => Animal('DONE'))

};
Hello();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: как-то все слишком сложно. вместо `forEach` в данном случае лучше использовать `reduce`. Что за _pause_? а, нашел

Comment: Код ужасен. Разбейте его на маленькие задачи и проверяйте какая именно из них не работает. Для таких задач очень удобно использовать generators .

Comment: Как я понимаю, почему-то обещания, находящиеся внутри массива (игнорируются) переносятся в конец всей цепочки(мб из-за присваивания chain..), но хотя нет, вроде. Когда я последовательно вклинивал это не используя функцию, а напрямую вставляя массив, он выполнялся как бы отдельно от всех обещаний и последующий текст выводился поверх паузы.

Comment: @mayst, сделай [mcve] чтобы можно было запустить и увидеть проблему

Comment: @Grundy, Т.е. закинуть в вопрос код, который можно было бы скопировать себе и протестировать?

Comment: @Grundy, сделано!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если пройтись по коду, то можно отметить, что функция Animal отличается от AnimalPause только тем, что в последней в итоге удаляется добавленный элемент.

Исходя из этого можно передавать созданный `p` в resolve функции `Animal` и удалять его если надо. При этом AnimalPause выродится в следующее

```
function AnimalPause(string) {
  return Animal(string).then(p => p.remove());
};
```

Далее идет основная ошибка: функция Pause, которая добавляет продолжения для

```
var chain = Animal(...)
```

Но при этом не возвращает итоговый Promise, а просто переводит себя в состояние готово, именно поэтому выполнения вывода паузы откладывается до следующей цепочки.

Вместо этого нужно вернуть Promise собранный на основе массива pause с помощью функции [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
function Pause(pause) {
  return pause.reduce((chain, txt) => chain.then(() => AnimalPause(txt)), Promise.resolve());
};
```

В этом случае возвращенный Promise будет встроен в существующую цепочку и вызван в нужном порядке.

---

Пример в сборе:

```js
var pause = [
  '...',
  '.....',
  '....',
  '.........'
];

function Animal(string) {
  var a = ''; //variable which will be entered character by character string
  var i = 0; //Letter counter
  var p = document.createElement('p');
  $('body').scrollTop($('body').append(p).height());
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    Anima();

    function Anima() { //Function of Animation   
      a += string[i];
      i++;
      p.textContent = a;
      var timer = setTimeout(Anima, 100);
      if (i == string.length) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        resolve(p);
      };
    };
  });
};

function AnimalPause(string) {
  return Animal(string).then(p => p.remove());
};


function Pause(pause) {
  return pause.reduce((chain, txt) => chain.then(() => AnimalPause(txt)), Promise.resolve());
};

function Hello() {
  var chain = Animal('..........')
    .then(() => Animal('---Hello! CONSOLE v 1.0.1 is working!---'))
    .then(() => Animal('To see all commands u can use type -help'))
    .then(() => Pause(pause))
    .then(() => Animal('DONE'))

};
Hello();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое как за исправленную ошибку, так и за разъяснения и дополнения по улучшению кода!

Comment: Я с ES 6 имел дело лишь на уровне ознакомления и.. Чертовски благодарен!!